# Is a .mp4 video file recorded in the WP Emulator ready for outside storage?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, mp4, isolatedstorage, windows-phone-7-emulator

**MS have released some code examples where a video is recorded in the WP Emulator and then saved in isolated storage. Is this .mp4 file ready to export away from the WP Emulator and play in other applications? Or is it needed to format it in some way or the other? If so, how to do it?**

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Inside+Windows+Phone/Inside-Windows-Phone-16-Mango-Camera-APIs

Source code for video recording is located in the WP project is called CameraUpload:

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=bc58fec5c97e307a&sc=documents&id=BC58FEC5C97E307A%21295

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394041(v=vs.92).aspx

Edit:

I am trying to upload a video recorded in the WP Emulator to Azure blob.

A file does get uploaded, but I am not able to play that file in Zune.

I would like to be able to play the video file recorded in the WP Emulator on Zune, what to do to enable this?

The method in the Azure WCF service role, which saves the video looks like this:
(Please forgive if the method parameters have slightly misdirecting and confusing names.)

```
bool SaveImage(int salesItemId, string contentType, byte[] photo);
```

The video is saved to a blob container named "firstmay".

The code in the phone client saving the video looks like this:

```
client.SaveImageAsync(77, "mp4", GetPhotoBytes(m_capturedFileName));

public byte[] GetPhotoBytes(string fileName)
{
    using (var appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
         IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = appStorage.OpenFile(m_capturedFileName,     FileMode.Open);
         byte[] buffer = new byte[isoStream.Length];
         isoStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)isoStream.Length); isoStream.Close();
         return buffer;
    }
}
```

When uploading a video from the WP client application, one first records a video and then uploads it by clicing "Save", it all goes on in the MainPage.

The client and server application can be downloaded from skydrive:

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=159250F5CE7FE134!118

Answer (score 0):

That'll all depend on what you want to be able to play back the content on. PCs with Zune would be fine, and I'd expect other video capable mobiles to be fine, but older mobiles, or standard Vista installs would require additional software, or transcoding of the video to be playable.

Comment: Hi Rowland Shaw, thank you for your response, so far I haven't been able to play a .mp4 file recorded in the WP Emulator on Zune. I have edited my question with some additional information about my setup.